"Here are more of the most amazing images of exploding cars you'll ever see." — What does "more of" mean here?
an article's headline from jalopnik.com:
(1) Here are more of the most amazing images of exploding cars you'll ever see.
What does "more of" mean here?
Does it mean the number of the most amazing images is greater than the number of some other images?
Does it mean the number of the most amazing images is greater than you'll ever see?

my variant with "than":
(2) Here are more of the most amazing images of exploding cars than you'll ever see.
Does "than" change the meaning which (1) had?
If it does, then how does it change?

my variant without "more of":
(3) Here are the most amazing images of exploding cars you'll ever see.
The presence of the phrase "you'll ever see" seems odd to me.
Is (3) correct?

Given that the first sentence in the article you linked starts with "Swiss photographer Fabian Oefner is back with a second part to his “Disintegrating” series," it can be inferred that the reason the author uses more of is in reference to part 1 of the series (i.e., an earlier article in the same magazine), which presumably featured some of the most amazing images of exploding cars...

Your confusion is understandable: Although the sentence is using these degree words correctly, it was perhaps a bad idea to put them so close together.

Overall, you have misunderstood the sentence.
More has the basic idea of additional to, but this meaning can vary depending on the phrase. In particular, more of is not the same as more than.

The chicken curry was so delicious that he asked for more of it. (He had some curry; he asked for more curry. Here more means "more of the same".)

She was sad because her brother got more chicken curry than her. (here more ... than is comparative. One serving of curry is bigger than the other.)


So in the sentence header there is a set of objects. The set consists of the most amazing images of exploding cars you'll ever see. It's a set of images. The images show exploding cars, and in the photographer's opinion they are the most amazing images you'll ever see. No one else has images this amazing.
Finally the header sentence says More of (these images). in other words, you saw a set of pictures in the previous article; now, here are some more. More of in this case means more of the same.
